How can I uniquely map all planar graphs to natural numbers?
How can I uniquely map all planar graphs to natural numbers?
I'm working on a problem where I want to create a bijection between all planar graphs and the natural numbers.
I first tried to map all connected graphs based on vertices $(v)$ and edges $(e)$ and got the following formula:
$IDX(v, e) = \frac{1}{6} v^3 - v^2 + \frac{11}{6} v + e$
This formula assigns a unique number to each pair $(v, e)$, and orders all connected graphs first by $v$, then by $e$.
However, the problem I'm facing is that there are still multiple distinct planar graphs with the same number of vertices and edges, meaning the mapping is not yet a bijection. I need a way to distinguish between different planar graphs that have the same v and e values.
I tried using Euler's formula to distinguish between non isomorphic graphs with the same $v$, $e$ but noticed that $f$ (number of faces) is dependent on $v, e$ so it's no use.
What additional information or graph invariants could I incorporate to ensure a bijection, and how might I go about doing this? Any insights into possible refinements or improvements to this approach would be greatly appreciated!

The set of planar graphs up to isomorphism? Seems unlikely there would be a simple injection, much less bijection, since it would give a simple solution to check graph isomorphism amongst planar graphs. If not up to isomorphism, you'd have to be more specific about the set of graphs you want

@ThomasAndrews perhaps a question to start with is the set of all planar connected graphs on lattice points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ where one still considers isomorphic but distinct graphs distinct

Maybe, but the OP should really be defining the question, not us guessing.

There is a bijection with $ℕ$ as clearly the set of planar (finite) graphs is countably infinite (countable union of all sets of planar graphs on $n$ vertices, which are finite). Do you somehow want a “nicer” bijection? If so, please be more specific on your goal.

there are infinitely countable planar graphs up to isomorphism (also true for just simple graphs), therefore there should be a bijection between them and the natural numbers.
my question is exactly an approach to the problem you showed @ThomasAndrews, that is why I try to think of more unique characteristics to graphs beside num of vertices and edges.

@JeanAbouSamra yes, trying to find a nice bijection is exactly the mission here.

Then you might want to look into the algorithms for testing graph isomorphism amongst planar graphs. This Wikipedia section cites this and this paper.

Just because we know there are countably infinite many things doesn't mean we can easily enumerate them with a useful formula. There are infinitely many prime numbers, but any $f$ is painfully slow. Essentially, we'd enumerate the finite graphs, then, as we enumerate them, reject if they are not planar, then reject if it is isomorphic to an already-enumerated graph, and, if not, enumerate this graph. But that isn't a "formula" that in any normal sense of the term, although it is an algorithm. It will be very inefficient

The real question is, why do you want such a function? It clearly exists, but we don't need to write it out. If you could give a reason/purpose for such a function, it might help.

@JeanAbouSamra thx a lot

@ThomasAndrews as weird as it seems, I don't know myself why lol, I did reduction from the planar graph isomorphism problem to Integer factorization, and I don't remember why but one thing leads to the other and I became obsessed with this question now... (:

Since you mention Euler's formula, it might be relevant to note that a single isomorphism class of planar graphs might have several nonequivalent embeddings, e.g., with nonisomorphic dual graphs. Perhaps you need to make your original problem explicit so we can judge what category you really need: graphs up to isomorphism, or something finer that includes embeddings of planar graphs in the plane.
